# Create object array base on different value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these data

```
[
    {
        "Month": 2,
        "SubjectID": 25,
        "TitleName": "TEST32",
        "Average": 85
    },
    {
        "Month": 4,
        "SubjectID": 1,
        "TitleName": "TEST",
        "Average": 63
    },
    {
        "Month": 4,
        "SubjectID": 25,
        "TitleName": "TEST32",
        "Average": 88
    }
]
```

i want to transform this into array object that will base on `subject id` and the `month`.
I don't know if this is possible.

but i want to create a year array where the `average` will display in array index of created array base on `month` number.

Output like this

```
    {
        name: 'TEST',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    {
        name: 'TEST32',
        data: [0, 85, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }
```

Comment: Worth giving it a shot to see how far you can get first.

Comment: Where does `84` come from? The numbers don't seem to match.

Comment: @Unmitigated sorry. ill just edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const data = [
  {
    "Month": 2,
    "SubjectID": 25,
    "TitleName": "TEST32",
    "Average": 85
  },
  {
    "Month": 4,
    "SubjectID": 1,
    "TitleName": "TEST",
    "Average": 63
  },
  {
    "Month": 4,
    "SubjectID": 25,
    "TitleName": "TEST32",
    "Average": 88
  }
];

const year = {};

// loop through each data item
data.forEach(item => {
  const { Month, SubjectID, TitleName, Average } = item;
  
  // if the SubjectID hasn't been seen yet, create an empty data array for it
  if (year[SubjectID] === undefined) {
    year[SubjectID] = {
      name: TitleName,
      data: Array(12).fill(0)
    };
  }
  
  // update the data array for the current month with the average
  year[SubjectID].data[Month - 1] = Average;
});

// convert the year object into an array of objects
const yearArray = Object.values(year);

console.log(yearArray);
// output:
// [
//   {
//     name: 'TEST32',
//     data: [0, 85, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
//   },
//   {
//     name: 'TEST',
//     data: [0, 0, 0, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
//   }
// ]
```

First create an empty object called year, which will store the data for each SubjectID. We then loop through each item in the data array and check if the SubjectID has been seen before. If it hasn't, we create a new object for it with an empty data array of length 12 (one for each month). If it has been seen before, we simply update the existing object's data array for the current month with the Average value.

Finally, we convert the year object into an array of objects using Object.values, and assign it to yearArray. This array contains one object for each unique SubjectID in the original data array, with the name property set to the TitleName and the data property set to an array of length 12 with the Average values in the appropriate positions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object to store the 12 averages for each name.

```js
let arr=[{Month:2,SubjectID:25,TitleName:"TEST32",Average:85},{Month:4,SubjectID:1,TitleName:"TEST",Average:63},{Month:4,SubjectID:25,TitleName:"TEST32",Average:88}];
let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {Month, SubjectID, TitleName : name, Average}) => {
  (acc[name] ??= {name, data: Array(12).fill(0)}).data[Month - 1] = Average;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: how double question mark works?

Comment: @Strywyr It's [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment): it only assigns the value if the left hand operand is `null` or `undefined`. It also does not evaluate the right hand side unnecessarily (it short circuits).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's `reduce()` sounds like a convenient function for your use case:

```
let arr = [
    {
        "Month": 2,
        "SubjectID": 25,
        "TitleName": "TEST32",
        "Average": 85
    },
    {
        "Month": 4,
        "SubjectID": 1,
        "TitleName": "TEST",
        "Average": 63
    },
    {
        "Month": 4,
        "SubjectID": 25,
        "TitleName": "TEST32",
        "Average": 88
    }
];

let result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let found = acc.find(x => x.name === item.TitleName);
    if (found) {
        found.data[item.Month - 1] = item.Average;
    } else {
        let newData = Array(12).fill(0);
        newData[item.Month - 1] = item.Average;
        acc.push({name: item.TitleName, data: newData});
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

#### How it works?

In the provided snippet, we're utilizing the `reduce()` function, which is an array method that allows us to reduce the array's contents to a single accumulated value — in this case, we're building a new array. The `reduce()` function iterate over each item in the original `data` array, and for each item:

- It creates a new array object for each unique `TitleName`, and populates its data array with `Average`s, indexed by `Month` (corrected to zero-based index).
- If an object with the same `TitleName` already exists, it updates the respective `Month`'s average.